# Swift 2 - catch 22 with Value of optional type not unwrapped

Tags: swift

I have following code in my AppDelegate

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    audioPlayer = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: bgMusicPath)

   }
}
```

Xcode says that

```
'Value of optional type 'AVAudioPlayer?' not uwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?' ?
```

and suggests to add the exclamation mark at the end of line 4 so it looks like this

```
audioPlayer = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: bgMusicPath)!
```

I try to build and again receive error at the same place. Now it says

```
Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type 'AVAudioPlayer'
```

And here Xcode suggests to delete exclamation mark which turns me to the beginning of the post after trying to build.

How to fix it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are sure the filename exists (and you want the failure to be a programming error), you don't need to `try?`. You can `try!`.
The difference is that `try?` will return an optional while `try!` will crash when the initialization fails.

In this case, I would use `try!`.

```
try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: bgMusicPath)
```

By the way, what Xcode was suggesting was this:

```
(try?  AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: bgMusicPath))!
```

but that's just a more complicated way of writing `try!`.

Comment: is you solution better than using if let audioPlayer =  AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: bgMusicPath) ? or they are the same ?

Comment: @AlexeyK in the if let case what do you do it it fails?

Comment: @Sulthan Is there any difference between `try` and `try?`, they seem to have the same documentation. (Try Operator, `The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2)`)

Comment: @zaph `try` is a part of do-catch block

Comment: And `try?` isn't? part of do-catch block? But they both have the same documentation when used this way. “If the expression does not throw an error, the value of the optional-try expression is an optional containing the value of the expression. Otherwise, the value of the optional-try expression is nil.”

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2).” iBooks. https://itun.es/us/jEUH0.l

Comment: `try?` converts the failure to a `nil` value. `try!` makes a failure crash. `do-try-catch` lets you access the thrown error (e.g. `NSError` from Obj-C frameworks).

Comment: I am asking about the difference between `try` and `try?` in a "Try Operator" usage, please see the iBook link.

Comment: @zapth I don't know which exact section you mean but `try?` consumes the error by converting the expression to an optional. `try` doesn't consume it so you have to either catch it using `do-catch` or `throw` up the call stack.

Comment: @Sulthan In that particular case I do nothing. What is good practice ?

Comment: @AlexeyK In this particular case, when you are loading a sound from your bundle, you want the application to crash if the loading fails because it means you have either forgot to include the file or the file has an invalid format. In other words, it's a programming error that should never happen in production so you want to know about it as fast as possible (app crash), you don't want to consume/ignore it.

Comment: @Sulthan Thanks! You described using "try" ? And if I use "if let" i will have not crash but runtime error in case of not have the file?

Answer (score -2):

Sorry haven't used Swift 2 yet but in 1.2 you could do the same (which should work in Swift 2 I think)

make your variable optional :

```
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()?
```

or use optional binding

```
if let audioPlayer =  AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: bgMusicPath)
```